# Restrictions Calling DLLs Across Technologies?

Tags: c#, c++, libraries, delphi, dll

I want to call a DLL in my programming language of 'choice'. The documentation surrounding this clearly states that it must be a 32-bit DLL written in C, C++ or Delphi. *But I wanted to call a DLL written in C#.* It goes on to mention that the default calling mode is **cdecl**.

So my question is: why would this be the case? Is there any way to make it *think* a C# DLL was written in C, C++ or Delphi?

Comment: Just to make sure, do you want to *call* the DLL in your language of choice, or do you want to call the DLL *written* in your langauge of choice? Are you basically supplying the DLL to a closed-box system, or are you writing the system and you want to call some DLL?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to call the DLL (written in C#) _from_ my language of choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That very problem is what COM was designed to address. I'll leave it to my good friend [Jeremiah Morrill to explain](http://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/com-for-the-i-did-c-once-a-thousand-years-ago-but-only-do-net-now-developer-or-in-the-defense-of-com/) what the problem is:

> I explained briefly how simple exporting regular “C” methods can be to
>   share code between DLLs and the application.  I also explained how C++
>   classes get flattened and compiled down and also how they are seen to
>   your CPU (more or less).  If C++ classes just get compiled to static
>   “C” methods, which can be exported from our DLL, is that not
>   sufficient to reuse and share classes across DLLs?  Yes…but not
>   without some major caveats as this would come at a cost.
>
> - The first disadvantage of exporting a C++ class is you must use the same C runtime in all DLLs/exe involved.  So if one DLL used MSVCRT7,
>     the caller of the DLL must be using MSVCRT7.  The reason is different
>     versions of C runtimes manage the heap differently, so if DLL A tried
>     to free resources allocated by DLL B, memory corruption can occur.
> - The second disadvantage is the same compiler version must be used.  This is because different compilers mangle names differently.  Name
>     mangling differences among compilers ensures a DLL built with
>     Microsoft would have completely different symbol names than a DLL
>     built with GCC.  So when linking of your code occurs, the linker might
>     be looking for “??4MyWidget…” when the export is really
>     “MyWidget__Fi…”
> - Third, if a large change of the base classes in DLL A are made, even without breaking API, then DLL B that uses the base classes must
>     be recompiled.
> - Forth [*sic*], if you take the last three disadvantages into consideration, we have a very tight coupling between our DLLs.  This
>     inhibits reusability of the module.
>
> Sometimes these issues are not an issue for a given project.  This is
>   usually acceptable when the project is small, or an in house utility. 
>   That’s totally fine.  But let’s pretend Microsoft ignored these
>   problems.  All developers would have to use the same compiler version.
>   Applications would have to be written for very specific versions of
>   Windows.  This would be a complete nightmare for everyone.

Looking at those problems, COM is a simple solution for solving them. By exposing your C# dll to COM, you can call it from any other COM compliant language.

Comment: I got up and running with COM, but to no avail... I'm either calling the method incorrectly, or my language (UniBASIC) is not COM compliant. Unfortunately there's such limited help and documentation available that I don't actually know which is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Your language of choice supports calling any native DLLs written in any language. It's not really limited to those made with C, C++ or Delphi. You could call Fortran DLLs too, for example.

The problem is that the C# DLL is a managed DLL. That's a completely different beast from a native DLL. You will need to put a bridging layer in between the C# and your code. Robert Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports is one simple way to do that.